# Getting xml from a post variable

Tags: php, xml, parsing, variables

I'm developing a website that needs to communicate with the payment service and this is done by them sending an XML file through a `post` variable to a receiver file that has to be created to get this information.

I'm using this but I cant get it to work right:

```
$xml_post = file_get_contents('php://input');
$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_post);
foreach($xml->children() as $child){
       $body .= $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
}
```

I need to get the information into variables.
Here is an example of the XML that I need to recieve:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<notification>
  <notificationtype>1</notificationtype>
  <operations>
    <operation>
      <type>1</type>
      <id>00214</id>
    </operation>
  </operations>
</notification>
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this line of code -

```
$body .= $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
```

you are appending with a `.`

This code is working fine at my end -

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('abc.xml');
foreach($xml->children() as $child){
       echo $body = $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br>";
}
```

`abc.xml` file contains -

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<notification>
  <notificationtype>1</notificationtype>
  <operations>
    <operation>
      <type>1</type>
      <id>00214</id>
    </operation>
  </operations>
</notification>
```

Output-

```
notificationtype: 1
operations:
```

---

Comment: :o I echoed the XML that I get from the POST variable and I get this:  

`Notification=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
    <notification>
     <notificationtype>1</notificationtype>
     <operations>
      <operation>
       <type>1</type>
       <id>00214</id>
      </operation>
     </operations>
</notification>`

What should I do in this case?

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman then ?? is it not working ?? i showed you the tested code..let me know whr exactly is the problem ??

Comment: I think the problem is "Notification=" I think that the XML is bad formated so I cant parse it properly

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman No i dont think so..when we are able to iterate it ..so i dont think ..double checked here as well http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_validate.asp

Comment: yep, it says that the first line has an error: where it says: `Notification=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>` Does it have anything to do about how i'm getting it from the posted variable?

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman your `Notification=` if it is in the output seems problem to me..let me know the case

Comment: Yep. its in the output, is there anyway I can delete that?

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman yeah u can ..`explode()` the string

Comment: @MatíasContrerasSelman if you face any problem .let me know then

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to solv the problem yet. As the server sends automatic XMLs to my reciver, I can't directly echo the XML so I'm sending it to my email. For some strange reason the only thing I get in my mailbox is `Notification=1100217` Any ideas?